# Одно и то же имя для разных моделей в разных приложениях Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm, django-model

У меня есть абстрактные приложение 1 и приложение 2 в Джанго проекте. Мне необходимо, чтобы в каждом приложении были свои таблицы с именами Task и File. И таблица File в каждом приложении ссылалась через ForeignKey на таблицу Task в своём же приложении. Выглядит это примерно так:

**app1.models**

```
class Task(BasicTask):
    task_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

class File(BasicFile):
    file_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Task_one')
```

**app2.models**

```
class Task(BasicTask):
    task_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

class File(BasicFile):
    file_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Task_two')
```

**main.models**

```
class BasicTask(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='+')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}. {self.name}"


class BasicFile(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.TextField()
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='+')
    content = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}. {self.unique_id}"
```

Проблема в том, что при создании миграций я получаю следующие ошибки:

```
ERRORS:
app2.Task.basictask_ptr: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'app2.Task.basictask_ptr' clashes with reverse accessor for 'app1.Task.basictask_ptr'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'app2.Task.basictask_ptr' or 'app1.Task.basictask_ptr'.
app2.Task.basictask_ptr: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'app2.Task.basictask_ptr' clashes with reverse query name for 'app1.Task.basictask_ptr'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'app2.Task.basictask_ptr' or 'app1.Task.basictask_ptr'.
app1.Task.basictask_ptr: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'app1.Task.basictask_ptr' clashes with reverse accessor for 'app2.Task.basictask_ptr'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'app1.Task.basictask_ptr' or 'app2.Task.basictask_ptr'.
app1.Task.basictask_ptr: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'app1.Task.basictask_ptr' clashes with reverse query name for 'app2.Task.basictask_ptr'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'app1.Task.basictask_ptr' or 'app2.Task.basictask_ptr'.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить данные ошибки?

Comment: Покажите `BasicTask` и `BasicFile`

Comment: @andreymal добавил в вопрос

Comment: Если вы не используете BasicTask и BasicFile напрямую, попробуйте сделать их абстрактными https://djbook.ru/rel3.0/topics/db/models.html#abstract-base-classes

Comment: @andreymal К сожелению, у меня есть необходимость их использовать, поэтому не могу сделать их абстрактными